# Why python want us this : Non-default argument follows default argument

Tags: python

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,value,parrent=None,neigh) -> None:
        self.val=value
        self.parrent=parrent
        self.neigh=neigh
```

Here I want to define a class. There is an error about neigh that *non-default argument follows default argument*. I saw the solution of this question but my main question is I want to know why python want us to do this?

Comment: The simple answer is Python's set rules. They do it so it is easier to intepret.

Comment: Consider a call like `Node(3, "x")`. Were you intending to set `parent == "x"`, and leaving `neigh` (supposedly required) undefined? Required parameters are syntactically required to precede optional ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Python allows omission of keyword / default-specified parameters and allows passing parameters without explicitly naming them.  If your definition was legal syntax (and the rest of the language functioned the same way), then instantiating

```
n = Node(4, 6)
```

might mean either

```
n = Node(value=4, parrent=6, neigh=None)
```

or

```
n = Node(value=4, parrent=None, neigh=6)
```

The point of syntax rules is to resolve ambiguities like this.